# Does Hazelcast Jet remoteMap sink make a putTransient call on the remote map?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I have 2 Hazelcast clusters both backed by same map Store.
I am trying to get some data from one cluster Imap and push it to the map of the second cluster.
What I want to know is if this makes a `put` or `putTransient` call on the remote map?

Comment: ok so I tried on local map and looks like it is a put call. Is there a way I can change that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It calls **map.putAllAsync()** for remote map.
See the code in WriteMapP.java

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/jet/impl/connector/WriteMapP.java#L140

```java
private boolean submitPending() {
  if (buffer.isEmpty()) {
    return true;
  }
  if (!tryAcquirePermit()) {
    return false;
  }
  setCallback(map.putAllAsync(buffer));
  resetBuffer();
  return true;
}
```